# Magento 2 update theme Snowdog/blank with custom theme

Tags: css, sass, themes, magento2

I am using Magento 2 for the first time and I decided to use Sass over Less for compiling css files. So I downloaded Snowdog/blank theme which I want to update with my own changes. I then added my own theme, which parent is Snowdog/blank. But when opening the project Url in a browser, I get there errors:

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../Magento_Braintree/css/source/module. on line 42 of ../pub/static/frontend/MyTheme/blank/en_US/css/styles.scss

Does anyone know how to use custom sass based theme?

Comment: Are you using frontools and gulp to compile?

Comment: No, I am using grunt. I also asked a question to Magento page, and I got the answer that there's a bug, so Sass theme doesn't work, and it is not fixed at the moment, so I am back at using Less for now.

Comment: The sass theme does work, but it doesn't support theme fallback. So what you need to do is copy all of the files into your theme folder.